# display webform table data based on serial no

Tags: webforms

i want just like for example display hospital based on location webform data from webform storing data of all hospital.

How to fetch data from webforms table and display it on page just as searching the data based on specific field like name or location?

Answer (score 0):

You can show this data using views module. Steps are below

1) Add new view and select in SHOW as webform submission Click continue and edit

2) In field section, add field as webform submission data:value, select webform node/formname and field you want.

In your example, hotel will be your form name and field name as name and location